# Display timestamp in django template

Tags: django, templates, date, timestamp

I need to display timestamp of a post with in django template. The timestamp would be like:

```
"timestamp":1337453263939 in milli seconds
```

I can convert the timestamp into datetime object and render it in the view. Is there is any direct way to display through the template?
The output should be:

```
print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1337453263.939))
2012-05-20 00:17:43.939000
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could use custom template filters (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/).
In your case it could like this:

1. Create directory 'templatetags' in application with view, that renders template.
2. Put into this dir blank file "__init__.py" and "timetags.py" with code:

   ```
   from django import template
   import datetime
   register = template.Library()

   def print_timestamp(timestamp):
       try:
           #assume, that timestamp is given in seconds with decimal point
           ts = float(timestamp)
       except ValueError:
           return None
       return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts)

   register.filter(print_timestamp)
   ```
3. In your template, add

   ```
   {% load timetags %}
   ```
4. Use following syntax in template:

   ```
   {{ timestamp|print_timestamp }}
   ```

   Where timestamp = 1337453263.939 from your example

This will print timestamp in local date and time format. If you want to customize output,
you can modify print_timestamp in following way:

```
import time
def print_timestamp(timestamp):
    ...
    #specify format here
    return time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(ts))
```

Comment: This does not comply with Django's DRY principles, @frnhr 's answer does

Comment: @tgdn This answers the OP's question, frnhr's answer doesn't. (I solves the inverse problem.)

Answer (score 96):

> Note: this answer actually solves the ***reverse*** problem
> (displaying a timestamp when having a datetime). The correct answer to
> OP (who has a timestamp and wants a datetime) is to make a custom template tag or filter, see the accepted answer
> for this.

---

```
{% now "U" %}
```

The `"U"` is a date format for Unix epoch, and can also be used with built-in [`date`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date) filter. So, if you have the date in a variable:

```
{{ value|date:"U" }}
```

Comment: sorry, the doc loading is too slow, so I didn't search it at the beginning. But this don't work for me, <td align='center'>{{ i.createTime|date:"U" }}</td>, the html show nothing. if only keep {{ i.createTime }}, it show numbers

Comment: According to the doc it should still work. Are you sure your `I.createTime` is a `DateTime` instance and not just an integer?

Comment: Yeah...my createTime is int which is an unix timestamp. But the 'timestamp' in question is the input(variable) not the output(display). First I use your solution because its simple but it doesn't work, after one hour struggle, I realize this. The accepted answer do the right

Comment: Watch out! The OP was asking for milliseconds since epoch, while the `"U"` formatting provides **seconds** since epoch. The result of `"U"` needs to be multiplied by 1000.

Comment: This answers a different question. The OP asks for _how to render the timestamp as a date/time string_, not _how to render the datetime object as a timestamp_.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the date filter:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#date

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the date filter takes timestamps, so unless I'm overseeing a filter, you could simply create one?

```
# python
from datetime import datetime

# django
from django import template


register = template.Library()

@register.filter("timestamp")
def timestamp(value):
    try:
        return datetime.fromtimestamp(value)
    except AttributeError, e:
        catch errors..
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write a custom filter that converts your timestamp string to a datetime object. Then you can either further process it into something readable (a string representing your time) and return it to your template or just return a python datetime object and use django's date filter.

So you could have something like this {{ timestamp_string|convert_to_datetime|date:'D d M Y' }}

More on this subject at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/