# addding 365days to date in python

Tags: python, datetime

I have to add 365 days to the date in a

```py
from datetime import datetime,timedelta,date
a = "2018-09-15 00:00:00"
year_add = datetime.strptime(a,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").date()
end_date = year_add + datetime.timedelta(days=365)
```

EXpected output = "2019-09-15 00:00:00"
I get error as:

AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add one year in current date PYTHON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741618/add-one-year-in-current-date-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding 5 days to a date in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871016/adding-5-days-to-a-date-in-python)

Comment: Your problem is with `datetime.datetime.strptime`, not with adding 365 days to it.

Comment: import datetime
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

Comment: Why did you import `datetime` twice?

Comment: Use `import datetime` or `from datetime import datetime`, but don't do both.

Answer (score 4):

```
from datetime import timedelta
import datetime
a = "2018-11-02"
out=datetime.datetime.strptime(a,'%Y-%m-%d')+timedelta(days=365)
print(out)
```

Comment: This helped me out as the single line "from datetime import timedelta, datetime" didn't work, but the additional "import datetime" did.