# Add a year to current date

Tags: python, date, time

```
from datetime import *

date = date.today()
```

Printing date gives me "2020-07-21"

How may I go about adding a year to that date?

Comment: I'd use `d.replace(d.year + 1)`. Also, avoid naming your variable `date`,you're shadowing the `date` imported from datetime

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add one year in current date PYTHON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741618/add-one-year-in-current-date-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from datetime import *
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

date = date.today()
newDate = date + relativedelta(years=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import  datetime as dt 
d = date.today()
dt.date(d.year + 1,d.month, d.day)
```

Comment: you loose the rest of the information (hour, minute, ...). Surely you mean `date(date.year + 1,date.month, date.day)`

Comment: Would be true if `date` contains precision of hour, minutes, sec, etc but `date.today()` has only day precision - oposite to `datetime.now()` which has full timestamp precision.

Comment: by using datetime you're adding including the time as well, which is not the question

Comment: Right, I've changed to `dt.date`, now no time part is added.