In my python code, timedelta(months=12) is not initializing
I am playing around with the datetime API and i am trying to add a full year to today's date. For some reason the code is throwing an error. This is what my code looks like
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
print(datetime.today().date() + timedelta(months=12))

This is giving me this error. The error is
TypeError: 'months' is an invalid keyword argument for __new__()

I don't know if i am missing something in this code.
I have tried just initializing timedelta in another variable without any arguments and it works. But when i add argument thats when it breaks. This is what i tried.
test = timedelta()


months isn't a valid parameter

I don't know if i am missing something Yes, you are missing that timedelta doesn't work that way.  months is not a parameter, just as the error says.

See https://stackoverflow.com/q/15741618/2308683

And the main reason it's not a valid parameter is that timedelta deals with exact time span, which month is not (it could be anywhere from 28 to 31 days). If you want to increment a date by a year, just replace the year by that same value + 1. Or use relativedelta which has all sort of rules to manage variable time deltas.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. I'm not sure what you're confused about here since the error message says exactly what the problem is. Do you understand what it's saying? Check out [ask] for tips, like starting with your own research. The docs are a good place to start researching. You can [edit] if needed.

Yeah. It was a pretty simple solve, i just had to use the days parameter. Apologies for the disrespect.

Note that one year isn’t always 365 days though…

Use the datetime replace() function instead.
from datetime import datetime
today = datetime.today().date()
this_day_next_year = today.replace(year=today.year+1)
print(this_day_next_year)

This will produce unexpected results if today's date does not exist in the next year (e.g. Feb 29).

For Feb 29, use dateutil.relativedelta instead. It returns Feb 28 next year.

A ValueError will be raised, not "unexpected results"
